# How to prevent casual changes in the folder for other processes?

Tags: python, windows, security

How to prevent casual changes in the folder for other processes?
I did it like this:

```
import os
username=os.environ.get("USERNAME")
os.system(r"echo y| cacls MyFolder /T /P %s:R > NUL"%username) # read only
os.system(r"echo y| cacls MyFolder /T /P %s:F > NUL"%username) # full access
```

What are the disadvantages of this?
What are the best ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the general case, you can't do this. The filesystem is best viewed as a multithreaded object over which you have no synchronization. ( http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2009/12/10/the-file-system-is-unpredictable.aspx?Redirected=true )

Your approach above modifies permissions such that the same user as your process can only read (or read/write) the file; it also blocks your own process in the same fashion.

Note of course that if you grant read access the user can copy the file somewhere else and modify it there.